# How to make checkbox change specific object property to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Started this todo app in react that takes input and adds the input to the array of objects. Each todo item has a checkbox next to it. I want when the checkbox is checked, completed of the specific property to change to either true or false depending on the initial value but I keep running to errors.

See function `isCompleted` and help me find a way to do this.

```
const Todos = () => {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Go to store",
      completed: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Buy groceries",
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Go to dinner with wife",
      completed: true
    }
  ]);

  const [work, setWork] = useState("");

  const newTodo = e => {
    setWork(e.target.value);
  };

  const addTodo = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodo(prevTodo => [
      ...prevTodo,
      { id: prevTodo.length + 1, title: work, completed: false }
    ]);
    setWork("");
  };

  const isCompleted = () => {
    setTodo(todo.map(todos => {
        if (todos.completed) {
            todos.completed = false
    }
    else {
        todos.completed = true
    }

  }))

  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={addTodo}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={work}
          onChange={newTodo}
          className="inputText"
        />
        <button>Add</button>
      </form>
      <div>
        {todo.map(todos => (
          <TodoItem
            key={todos.id}
            title={todos.title}
            completed={todos.completed}
            id={todos.id}
            isCompleted={isCompleted}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass in the id of the specific `todo` to mark just that one as completed.

```
const isCompleted = (id) => {
  setTodo(todo.map(todos => {
      if (todos.id === id) {
          todos.completed = true;
      }
      return todos;
  }))
};

...

<TodoItem
  key={todos.id}
  title={todos.title}
  completed={todos.completed}
  id={todos.id}
  isCompleted={() => isCompleted(todos.id)}
/>
```